# FPDF: insert variable into PDF

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

Using FPDF2 and Python3 to create a report. Would like to insert a string into a PDF but cannot see how to do it.
Just cannot find the syntax.

Something simple like:

```
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin

class PDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass 
name="Chris"

pdf = PDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.write_html("""
<h1>My name -{name} should print here</h1>
""")
pdf.output("htmlnew.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using an `f` string:

```py
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin

class PDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass 
name="Chris"
... 

pdf.write_html(f"""<h1>My name {name} should print here</h1>""")

...
```

Comment: Well that worked - thank you so much. 
Now I must find out more about this 'f string' of which you speak.